# Text wrap in TableItem

Tags: eclipse, swt, tableviewer, styledtext

This is about wrapping text in a table item, I know table item doesn't support WRAP. But I am looking at possibility of embedding a StyledText inside the tableitem. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that, but there is a facility called owner draw that allows you to paint tree and table items however you like.

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html

Comment: can we implement WRAP with that facility? I don't see an example.

Comment: Sure you can, but you will likely need to handle calculating how text wraps so that you can paint it appropriately.